# Adding `onLongPressGesture` to SwiftUI Text view prevents scrolling?

Tags: swiftui, vertical-scrolling, uilongpressgesturerecognizer

In a Multiplatform SwiftUI app I'm developing, I have a Text view embedded in a scroll view. I want to add a long press gesture to the Text view that lets the user copy the contents to the clipboard.

When I do that, the iOS version no longer scrolls the text when you press on the contents and drag. Below is the code in question. Is there a way to support both scrolling and a long press gesture recognizer?

(In UIKit you can make a gesture recognizer only fire when others fail. I suspect the long press gesture recognizer is intercepting the touch event and preventing the ScrollView from getting it.)

```
ScrollView() {
    // MARK: Resuts word list
    Text(anagramsState.wordList)
        .lineLimit(nil)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        .frame(minWidth: geometry.size.width - 2, minHeight: 20, alignment: .topLeading)
        .onLongPressGesture {
            if copyTextToClipboard(anagramsState.wordList) {
                anagramsState.statusMessage = "Results copied to clipboard."
            } else {
                anagramsState.statusMessage = "Long press ignored."
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: How about using `.textSelection(.enabled)` to enable copying instead?

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about that. That sounds like an excellent solution. Would you mind posting that as an answer, and if it works I'll accept it? (Although I'm still curious as to why adding a long press gesture recognizer blocks scrolling {I have a suspicion as to why} and how to fix it.)

Comment: `.textSelection(.enabled)` does indeed show an edit menu, but all it lets me do is copy the entire contents of the `Text` field to the clipboard, or bring up a share menu. I would have enabling "textSelection" to let me tap and drag to select a range of text, double-tap to select words, etc.

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately it only does that on macOS. Your goal is to copy the entire text anyway, right? So it doesn't matter in this particular case.

Comment: I'd like to enable both. It's useful to be able to select words OR the whole contents. Enabling a "look up" button like on web views would be awesome, but unless you can select words I wouldn't be able to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI currently has very few modifiers that allows you to fiddle with the built-in gesture recognisers of scroll views. The only one I can think of off the top of my head is [`presentationContentInteraction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/presentationcontentinteraction(_:)), which is rather irrelevant here.

If your goal is to just allow the user to copy the entirety of the `Text`, you can use [`textSelection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/textselection(_:)):

```
Text("some text")
    .textSelection(.enabled)
```

Note that the behaviour on macOS is different from that on iOS:

> On macOS, people use the mouse or trackpad to select a range of text, which they can quickly copy by choosing Edit > Copy, or with the standard keyboard shortcut.

> On iOS, the person using the app touches and holds on a selectable `Text` view, which brings up a system menu with menu items appropriate for the current context. These menu items operate on the entire contents of the `Text` view; the person can’t select a range of text like they can on macOS.

If the `ScrollView` contains only the `Text`, consider using a `TextEditor` instead. You can pass it a `constant` binding to disable editing:

```
TextEditor(text: .constant("Some Text"))
```

This allows selecting specific ranges of text.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. The options for text selection seem... less than adequate.

Comment: I guess it's time to wrap a UITextView into SwiftUI and use that.

Comment: @DuncanC Actually, if the scroll view only has the `Text`, you can use a `TextEditor(text: .binding("some text"))`. The constant binding makes it uneditable, but still selectable.

Comment: That gives me an error that `Type 'Binding<String>' has no member 'binding'`. (And I would want a constant biding to an @Published variable since I want it to react to changes to the variable.)

Comment: @DuncanC oops I made a typo in the comment. See the edit in the answer instead. It should be `constant`. And yes, you can pass `anagramsState.wordList` in there.

Comment: Using `TextEditor(text: .constant)` works really well, EXCEPT that when you tap inside the text editor, it displays the software keyboard. In my app the text editor is down near the bottom of the screen, and that has the effect of forcing the text editor's frame to shrink down to almost zero height, so selecting text is impossible. Is there a way to defeat that? (It seems like a bug to display the keyboard when the text isn't editable.)

Comment: @DuncanC Oh that was an oversight from me. I was running on the simulator and so the software keyboard didn't pop up. It makes sense for the keyboard to show up, because `TextEditor` doesn't give special treatment to `Binding.constant`, and set `UITextView.isEditable` to false. All it does when the user tries to edit the text is to set the binding's value, but a `.constant` binding doesn't do anything when it is set, causing the text to be "uneditable" as a result.

Comment: @DuncanC I recently found a [library](https://github.com/siteline/swiftui-introspect) that allows you to access the UIKit components that SwiftUI uses under the hood (e.g. `TextEditor` uses `UITextView` under the hood). This might be a good alternative if writing your own `UIViewRepresentable` is too much work.

Comment: That library looks good, but it requires that you specify the OS versions to introspect, so it's not future-proof, which is unfortunate. (I'd have to update the app to include new OS versions as they are released.)

Comment: Sigh. When I try to add the swiftui-introspect package to my project, it works on the sim, but when I try to run on a device, or run the Mac version, I get an error "No such file or directory: '~/...DerivedData... PackageFrameworks/SwiftUIIntrospect-Dynamic.framework/Versions/A/SwiftUIIntrospect-Dynamic'." The package.swift file seems to be set up to build `SwiftUIIntrospect`, `SwiftUIIntrospect-Static`, and `SwiftUIIntrospect-Dynamic`, but the linker can't find the dynamic library version for some reason.

Comment: I had to manually remove the static and dynamic versions of the swiftui-introspect library from my project before. I could build for device, but once I did it works a treat to let me set the underlying UITextField/NSTextField of my TextEditor to `.isEditable=false`.